# Is it possible to enable the mssql module in php without modifying php.ini file?

Tags: php, sql-server

How to enable mssql module in php without modifying php.ini file.

Actually i don't have access the server settings ,where the  my site in uploaded.

Can i able to achieve this with any php codes
like ini_set()

Comment: Note, once in a while a host will set things up so that you can have a php.ini in some other place (sometimes the same place as your scripts), and set your own stuff up there.  Not sure whether that'd include loading extensions, though.

Comment: so can i do it by php code.If yes ,can you give its example

Comment: No, you can't do it in PHP itself.  By the time PHP code is running, the extension loading stage has already passed.  You can't just up and load another extension after that.

Comment: Oh ok, so only way is uncomment the mssql line in php.ini file, right?

Comment: Effectively, yeah.  But of course, you'll need to make sure the module is actually there.  If it's not, depending on your setup, PHP might not work....or, if it's running as a module in your web server, you might take down the server.  That's why most hosts don't let you set it directly.

Comment: cHao,Thanks for your reply . I got the php.ini file from the server administrator.But i can't find  ;extension=php_mssql.dll .Do you have any idea ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17264/discussion-between-linto-and-chao)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done!

note: Your shared hoster must run windows (many run linux) and must have sql server installed. If it is a windows machine, then the only way to enable mssql is to modify the ini file, and restart the webserver.

Answer (score 1):

modules are loaded on php's (webservers) start. You cannot do that afterwards